# HTMLAgilityPack - XPath - Dynamic Table Null Reference

Tags: c#, html, dom, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm using the HTMLAgilityPack and mostly works fine however on this particular website, the XPath returns a null when it should return a value. I tried various XPath and none seem to work. If someone can pinpoint the problem. I also want to point out that the website table is dynamic if it makes any difference.

Also I tested the XPath in XPath Helper Chrome Add-on and it shows the correct value but returns null in HTMLAgilityPack.

```
string Url = "http://weather.deltixlab.com";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);

string day1 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"free-data-table\"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]").InnerText;
```

Below is a snippet of the HTML as well as the site link: http://weather.deltixlab.com

[image]

Comment: When you reduce the XPath bit by bit from the end, what is the longest bit that still returns something?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem in web page working principle. Page load content into home section after loading via web socket.

May be it will be more easily to use webbrowser control to load page completly and parse data via DOM?

If such a decision is acceptable i can write litle code for your.

Comment: I see so the only way is to render the page completely and than parse the table via xpath. If you can post a solution that for optimal speed as now I feel this solution will cause a delay in processing. No?

Comment: Yes. In the case with webbrowser you shoold make a delay by your self. For example 5 seconds. Is it good? If yes, i will write.

Comment: 3 sec should be fine. I'm also looking at other possible solutions using a headless browser like selinium but your answer should point me in the right direction

Comment: Also you can hook connection with websocket api, analyze, and realyze by your self. Its more hard, but faster.

Comment: privet :) I wasnt sure if you were going to write an example or not but just as an update...I used PhantomJS and Selenium together for a headless browser but my results is coming out as "Element (id = :wdc: random number". Below is my code.

`IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(); driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://weather.deltixlab.com"); var myNode = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='free-data-table']/tbod‌​y/tr[1]/td[2]"));`